# Radio button not working as expected vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Radio button are now getting on my nerves.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xJmz.png)

From above image my problem is clearly visible.
I want that only one radio button can be selected at a time.
I made first radio button's group TRUE and also attached only 1 variable to the first radio button. still not working.

Comment: Make sure all the radio buttons are next to each other in the tab order. My guess is, you have other controls in tab order between radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks...That works...

Comment: ... and the first in Tab order should have the Property Group= True and all others should have Property Group= False.